# How long do Azure notification hub registration Ids last for?

Tags: azure

While the pns-handles registered to a registration Id have an expiration date, how long does a registration Id last for?

Answer (score 1):

Registration expires in 90 days **if it is not updated**. Expired registrations are automatically deleted from system.

Usually each time application starts on device it receives PNS handle and updates registration to avoid expiration of registration or PNS handle.